# How to deduce the following trig relation?

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, proof-writing, radicals

How can I deduce:

$$\sqrt{|x|}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \le \sqrt{|x|}$$??

I know of the relation.

$$\sin(u) \le u$$
$$u = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\sin(1/x) \le \frac{1}{x}$$

But nothing related to $\sqrt{x}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we have for $x\not=0\in\mathbb R$
$$\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)\le 1,$$
multiplying the both sides by $\sqrt{|x|}\gt 0$ gives us
$$\sqrt{|x|}\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)\le \sqrt{|x|}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** 

 You have that
$$\sin u\leqslant 1\quad\text{for all $u\in\Bbb R$},$$ and see what happens if you multiply both sides with $\sqrt{|x|}$.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the fact that $\sin(y)\leq 1, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence you have

$$\sqrt{|x|}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \le \sqrt{|x|} \times 1 = \sqrt{|x|}$$

As desired.

Answer (score 2):

For any $\;x\neq 0\;$ (obviously), we have

$$\sqrt{|x|}\sin\frac1x\le\sqrt{|x|}\iff \sin\frac1x\le \frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}= 1$$

which is trivial.